# How to check in web content template that structure date field is disabled in Liferay?

Tags: templates, liferay, structure, web-content

How to check that web content/structure field is disabled in Liferay?

Any help would be appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: Could you add some more details? At which point do you want to check it? What do you mean with _disabled_?

Comment: Liferay is adding checkbox(Disabled) for the date field, i wanted to check if there is a way to check whether the filed is disabled or not?

Comment: I still don't get it: where can I find `checkbox(Disabled)`? In JavaScript? In the UI? Please provide a [mcve](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).